# Entity Framework 4.1: how to work with per call life time data context?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, concurrency, datacontext

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160152/entitty-framework-life-of-datacontext), I am using a data context per call, so in each method of my WCF service, I use a *using block* to create a new data context.

But I have some doubts in the form to work in this way.

For example, I use a method getAllCLients() from my repository to get all the clients of the data base, then the service send to the client that call the method a list with all the clients. Then the user modify the information of some of them, three for example. The modify client perhaps I can add to a list that have the modified clients.

When I want to update this three clients, I can call a method updateClients() which receive a list of modified clients. How I am use a new data context per each method, in updateCients() get a new dataContext, without entities, so I think that I have to follow this steps:

1.- create a new data context which has the clients that I want to update. SO I need to specified the conditions for that. This is an extra operation (I get the clients before with the getAllClients() method), so I need to get again the clients.

2.- go throw the clients collection of the DBSet (I use EF 4.1) and change the information. This makes me to go throw the list that I receive from the client application too. So I must to go throw two lists. This needs resources.

3.- save the changes. This is needed anyway, so it has no required more work.

There is any way to make the step 2 easily? exist some method in dataContext to pass the values from my modified client to the client in the data context? I use POCO entities, perhaps it exists an easy way to do that.

Other question is about concurrency. If I control the concurrency with pesimistic concurrency that allow EF (with a timestamp field for example), is it better to call the updateClient() one for each client or better to pass a list with all the clients? I mean that if I use a list as parameter, if there is a concurrency issue with one client,the second for example, the first client will be update correctly, but the second not and the third neither. How can I notify to the user that there is problems with some clients?

To resume, I would like to know the best way to make updates when I have a short life datacontext.

Thanks.
Daimroc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service is disconnected scenario so when your client passes backs modified records you just need to process them as modified. You don't need to load all records from database for that.

```
public void SaveClients(List<Client> modifiedClients)
{
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        modifiedClients.ForEach(c => 
           {
               context.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
           });
        context.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

If you are using per call service and every service operation needs context you can move your context instancing to service constructor because service instance will live only to server single service call = you don't need `using` for every call. If you do that don't forget to implement `IDisposable` on your service to dispose context.

> Other question is about concurrency. If I control the concurrency with
>   pesimistic concurrency that allow EF (with a timestamp field for
>   example), is it better to call the updateClient() one for each client
>   or better to pass a list with all the clients?

EF doesn't support pesimistic concurrency out of the box. Using timestamp is optimistic concurrency because it allows others to use the record. Pesimistic concurrency is application logic where other client is not able to select locked record for update.

The concurrency is resolved per record but the problem in this case is transaction. Each call to `SaveChanges` results in transaction used to process all changes in the database. So if any of your modified records is not up to date you will get concurrency exception and whole transaction is rolled back = no record is updated.

You can still overcome the issue by passing list of modified records to the service (reducing roundtrips between client and service is a best practice) but you can process each record separately by calling `SaveChanges` for every single record. Anyway this should be very carefully considered because each call to `SaveChanges` is like separate unit of work - is it really what you want?

Btw. the best practice is to make your service statless. You should avoid maintaining data between service calls and this example really doesn't need it.

Comment: Well, my idea to maintaining data from calls it's because a user have a level access privileges, and also I want to send to the client only the data that is for the user, so I would like to konw some data of the conected client, like the level privileges and the callback. So I think that per session it was the best option. Also I would like to you callbacks. is it possible to use a duplex in a per call service? Thanks.

Comment: No duplex scenario requires session.

Comment: how can I know the client (the callback) which I want to call?


Thanks.

Comment: in an static list, for example? this makes me to in each method, check if the callback exists in the list or not. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you need some global shared code which will be used to register callbacks.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very nice answer. This helped me to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542413/context-per-request-how-to-update-entity